# Prolog Kbase implementation

Tags: prolog

[image]

So my approach to this problem is logical. And everything works as expected. My code is below:

```
employees(billSmith).
employees(bobJones).
employees(lindaHiggs).

married(billSmith,karenSmith).

parent(billSmith,tonySmith).
parent(billSmith,lauraSmith).

ensured(X) :- 
   employees(X),
   (  parent(X,_)
   ;  married(X,_)
   ).
```

Sample query:

```
?- ensured(X).
X = billSmith ;
X = billSmith ;
X = billSmith ;
false.
```

**My question:** I am getting the right output, but why is my output redundant? How can I transform my implementation to get a single non-duplicate answer?

Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you could add a cut to ensured/1 to commit done choices, but your rule seems wrong - doesn't addresses dependents

Comment: You are definitely **not** getting the right output. Every name mentioned in your problem statement except for Laura Smith is insured (she is not a minor). You also misspelled "insured". (This is, btw, a very strange way of writing names, but I guess you didn't come up with the problem statement).

Comment: If you actually put all information in the form of facts in the database, you will find it somewhat easier to formulate your query. At the moment, you are missing some of it.

Answer (score 0):

just an hint: complete you KB as needed

```
ensured(X) :-  employees(X).
ensured(X) :-  employees(E), parent(E, X), age(X, A), A < 18.
...
```